# Taking camera input, changing it in a canvas element, and returning it back as a MediaStream is failing

Tags: html

I have a simple application that takes camera input, converts it to a canvas (where the stream can be manipulated) and then returns the manipulated stream back via `captureStream`. However, it seems like the stream isn't returning anything as the output video is black.

Can someone point out where I went wrong here?

The copy below can be copy/pasted and run.

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <video id="video-id" playsinline autoplay></video>
</body>

<script type="application/javascript">
    const video = document.getElementById('video-id');

    function manipulatedVideoStream(stream) {
        const temp_video = document.createElement('video');
        const temp_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        temp_video.srcObject = stream;

        const framerate = 1000 / 30; // ~30 fps
        setInterval(() => {
            temp_canvas.width = temp_video.videoWidth;
            temp_canvas.height = temp_video.videoHeight;
            const context = temp_canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(temp_video, 0, 0, temp_video.width, temp_video.height);

            // draw some stuff in here

        }, framerate);
        return temp_canvas.captureStream(framerate);
    }

    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: true
    };

    function handleSuccess(stream) {
        video.srcObject = manipulatedVideoStream(stream);
    }

    function handleError(error) {
        console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The temp_video needs to be set on autoplay.

```
temp_video.autoplay = true;
```